# Divide a value by another value if a condition is met in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

[DataFrameExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQUC9.png)

All I want is to return the current liquidity, which meand I want to divide the 'Ativo Circulante' (Current assets) by the 'Passivo circulado' (current liaiabilities) for every year of the DataFrame I've done it iterating over it, but i'm trying to find a smarter solution.

I'm trying to store the return in a list of tuples like [(2010, current liquidity), (2011, current liquidity)] and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `pandas.pivot_table()` :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'a',10],[1,'b',20],[2,'a',30],[2,'b',10],[3,'a',10],[3,'b',60]],columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
df1 = df.pivot_table(index=['col1'],columns='col2').reset_index()
df1.columns = ['col1','a','b']
df1['c'] = df1['a']/df1['b']
```

Also, you can now `merge` this `df1` back into your original `df`.

[image: screenshot of the output]